# extract conditional max based on a reference data frame

Tags: pandas

my reference data frame is of the following type:

```
tbl = pd.DataFrame([['Afghanistan', 'AFN',  4],
                   ['Albania',  'ALL',  2],
                   ['France',   'EUR',  1]],
                     columns=['country',    'currency', 'score'])
```

a toy working `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[['France','AFN'],['France','ALL'],['France','EUR'],
['Albania','AFN'],['Albania','ALL'],['Albania','EUR'],
['Afghanistan','AFN'],['Afghanistan','ALL'],['Afghanistan','EUR']], 
columns=['country','currency'])
```

As my working `df` may have country and currency differently, for example `country =='France'` and `'currency'=='AFN'`,  I would like to create a column with max score based on either, i.e., this country/currency combo would imply a score of 4.
Desired output:

```
Out[102]: 
       country currency  score
0       France      AFN      4
1       France      ALL      2
2       France      EUR      1
3      Albania      AFN      4
4      Albania      ALL      2
5      Albania      EUR      2
6  Afghanistan      AFN      4
7  Afghanistan      ALL      4
8  Afghanistan      EUR      4
```

Here is what I have so far, but it's multiline and extremely clunky:

```
df = pd.merge(df, tbl[['country', 'score']],
             how='left', on='country')
df['em_score'] = df['score']
df = df.drop('score', axis=1)

df = pd.merge(df, tbl[['currency', 'score']],
             how='left', on='currency')
df['em_score'] = df[['em_score', 'score']].max(axis=1)
df = df.drop('score', axis=1)
```

Comment: If it is the case, either country or currency will have different score for the same value, i.e. (france, 1)  when EUR and (france, 4) when AFN. .What score to choose ? the max of the max?

Comment: what is `df`? you did not provide it

Comment: @RicVillalba   apologies, i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```py
byCol = {col:tbl[[col,'score']].set_index(col) for col in tbl.columns if col != 'score'}
df['em_score'] = pd.concat([
    df.join(byCol[col], on=col).score.rename('score_' + col) for col in byCol
    ], axis=1).max(axis=1)
```

Explanation:

- for each column in `tbl` other than `score` (in your case, `country` and `currency`), create a Series with that column as index
- use `pd.concat()` to create a new dataframe with multiple columns, each a Series object created using `join()` between the working `df` and one of the Series objects from the previous step
- use `max()` on each row to get the desired `em_score`.

---

Full test code with sample `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
tbl = pd.DataFrame([['Afghanistan', 'AFN',  4],
                   ['Albania',  'ALL',  2],
                   ['France',   'EUR',  1]],
                     columns=['country',    'currency', 'score'])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['France','AFN'],['France','ALL'],['France','EUR'],
    ['Albania','AFN'],['Albania','ALL'],['Albania','EUR']], 
    columns=['country','currency'])
print('','tbl',tbl,sep='\n')
print('','df',df,sep='\n')

byCol = {col:tbl[[col,'score']].set_index(col) for col in tbl.columns if col != 'score'}
df['em_score'] = pd.concat([
    df.join(byCol[col], on=col).score.rename('score_' + col) for col in byCol
    ], axis=1).max(axis=1)
print('','output',df,sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
tbl
       country currency  score
0  Afghanistan      AFN      4
1      Albania      ALL      2
2       France      EUR      1

df
   country currency
0   France      AFN
1   France      ALL
2   France      EUR
3  Albania      AFN
4  Albania      ALL
5  Albania      EUR

output
   country currency  em_score
0   France      AFN         4
1   France      ALL         2
2   France      EUR         1
3  Albania      AFN         4
4  Albania      ALL         2
5  Albania      EUR         2
```

Answer (score 2):

So, for case if you have

```
tbl = pd.DataFrame([['Afghanistan', 'AFN',  4],
                   ['Albania',  'ALL',  2],
                   ['France',   'EUR',  1],
                   ['France',   'AFN',  0]],
                     columns=['country',    'currency', 'score'])
```

This code will find the max of either the max score for the country or the currency of each row:

```
np.maximum(np.array(tbl.groupby(['country']).max().loc[tbl['country'], 'score']),
           np.array(tbl.groupby(['currency']).max().loc[tbl['currency'], 'score']))
```